# functions.php cause white-screen and media-library issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I disable all plugins, all white-space and php comments in the `function.php`.

but problem not solved.

when i remove all code in the `function.php` the problem is solved but if write `<?php ?>` in the file the problem return

`functions.php` cause white-screen and media-library not loaded.Here the `function.php`:

```
<?php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);
function my_theme_wrapper_start() { echo '<section class="header">'; }
function my_theme_wrapper_end() { echo '</section>'; }
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 70, 150 );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );                        
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
function arphabet_widgets() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'sidebar',
        'id' => 'right-panel',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="panel">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets' );
function search() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'search',
        'id' => 'search-panel',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="panel">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'search' );
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
?>
```

how to fix it?!

Comment: Turn on debugging. It'll give you a specific line number with the problem. Magic, I tell ya.

Comment: @rnevius Amen. How to do it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the PHP-ending tag ?> from the file functions.php. It is unneccessary and I've encountered situations where whitespace / line breaks that come after "?>"-tag cause WordPress to throw a blank screen, because headers are sent too early / multiple times (Headers already sent).

Comment: Holy smokes, this saved my day (6+ years after you wrote it – I just love StackOverflow)! My WordPress site broke after upgrading to v5.5.5, and the `?>` followed by a couple of newlines seems to have been the culprit.